# Horizontal menu vertical padding on anchor tag doesn't take affect

Tags: css, css-float

I am wondering why in the following example the top and bottom padding has no affect on the anchor tag while the left and right does?

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
</ul>

    #nav{
        list-style:none;
    }
    #nav li{
        border:1px solid #666;
        display:inline;
       /*If you do it this way you need to set the top and bottom 
         padding to be the same here as under #nav li a
        padding:8px 0; */
    }
    #nav li a{
        padding:8px 16px;
    }
```

Example: [Link](http://www.levijackson.net/test/HorizontalMenu/horizMenu.html)

So my main question is, why does the top and bottom padding not have an effect on the list items while the left and right do?

I did try [this out](http://www.levijackson.net/test/HorizontalMenu/horizMenu2.html) with a float instead of a display:inline on the list item and it worked as I expected it to.  So I guess if I had a secondary question it would be what is the difference between a float:left; and a display:inline? I was reading [the float spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) and it sounds like a float is still a box online inline so somewhat like inline-block?

I appreciate any input, this isn't really something I need to know to finish a project or anything, but I would like to know why.

Thanks
Levi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anchors are inline elements. Only block level elements can have top/bottom attributes changed.

You can override by doing:

```
a
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

The float is neccessary because block level elements take up the entire width of the container they're in. You'll have to write some extra rules to clear it at some point. Either way, have a play about to see how it works.

Comment: I prefer to style the LI as float:left, then use display:block, padding, border and margin on the A itself.

Comment: Using a CSS reset can also help maintain consistency between browsers when using lists. See: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/

Comment: There are endless ways of acheiving the desired result. I'd never set all anchors to block, but it was just a straight forward example :)

Comment: @Diodeus - Ah yes, in my second example above I did just that.
@Danten - Thanks for the answer, do you happen to know where I could find some documentation on inline versus block and the differences?  I  read through this http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html but didn't see it explicitly say inline can't have top/bottom attributes changed.

Comment: Levi: I garnered most of my practical design knowledge from a book titled Bulletproof Webdesign. If you can get it for cheap its worth it, even though its a few yers old now. As for the differences between inline and block, try this link http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline.php. The most important difference is that blocks span across the whole page while inlines don't.

Answer (score 4):

An obscure corner of the CSS spec actually points out that `display: block` is an unnecessary companion to `float: left`.

The **reason** for the pointless padding is... inline elements.  Interesting fact: inline elements will take padding values, but that padding won't affect the layout of surrounding content.

To get the desired results given the markup and styles above, I would suggest simply changing the `display` value of the `li` elements to `inline-block` and using a `line-height` value or `position: relative` etc. to control the vertical composition of the links while confining all of your box values to the list items.

The older the browser, the buggier these styles will be; details on that could go on for several paragraphs.

There are three support issues to remember when working with solutions like these:

1. In IE6 `display: inline-block` is only applied to elements that have a runtime `display` value of `inline`.  The HTML4 spec can help you tell the sheep from the goats on that one.
2. Firefox 2.x doesn't support the `inline-block` value, but does have a `-moz-inline-block` CSS extension.
3. Interstitial source whitespace is rendered between inline-block elements as it is between inline elements, which might bring undesirable results in the absence of careful source markup formatting.

Comment: Ben, thanks for ".. inline elements will take padding values, but that padding won't affect the layout of surrounding content." I long forgot about this behavior and was surprised when I declared padding-bottom on a navigation link to offset its underline - "just tried" expecting it to not work - and it worked! Search for explanation brought me here. Handy (intended?) behavior to use in decoration classes like `.current-page` in navigation.